# Xamarin Android Error inflating a custom widget from a java bound library

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, android-custom-view, java-binding, xamarin-binding

Currently I'm trying to get up and running Google VR's simple `VrPanoramaView` using Xamarin.

I've used this [project (Xamarin Components)](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinComponents/tree/d24d35b962c910edbeed3e338ae2f405d36041b5/XPlat/GoogleVR/Android/source) to manually bind the Java libraries. Binding the project, and more specifically, the **PanoWidget**, resulted in the following: [PanoWidget image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNqik.png)

I get the following code when I use the Object Browser to look into `VrPanoramaView`'s C# code (partially included code):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Android.Runtime;

namespace Google.VR.SDK.Widgets.Pano {

    // Metadata.xml XPath class reference: path="/api/package[@name='com.google.vr.sdk.widgets.pano']/class[@name='VrPanoramaView']"
    [global::Android.Runtime.Register ("com/google/vr/sdk/widgets/pano/VrPanoramaView", DoNotGenerateAcw=true)]
    public partial class VrPanoramaView : global::Google.VR.SDK.Widgets.Common.VrWidgetView {
        [...]
        [...]
        [...]
        // Metadata.xml XPath constructor reference: path="/api/package[@name='com.google.vr.sdk.widgets.pano']/class[@name='VrPanoramaView']/constructor[@name='VrPanoramaView' and count(parameter)=2 and parameter[1][@type='android.content.Context'] and parameter[2][@type='android.util.AttributeSet']]"
        [Register (".ctor", "(Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;)V", "")]
        public unsafe VrPanoramaView (global::Android.Content.Context p0, global::Android.Util.IAttributeSet p1)
        : base (IntPtr.Zero, JniHandleOwnership.DoNotTransfer) {
            [...]
            [...]
            [...]
         }
    }
}
```

From what I can understand the `VrPanoramaView` has been registered and is supposedly accessible by referencing it in the following way in a layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <com.google.vr.sdk.widgets.pano.VrPanoramaView
    android:id="@+id/pano_view"
    android:layout_margin="5dip"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="@null"
    android:layout_height="250dip" />

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/MyButton"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="@string/Hello" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Nevertheless, when I build and deploy the application I get the following error:

```
Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class com.google.vr.sdk.widgets.pano.VrPanoramaView
```

More specifically, it seems like it can't find the class:

```
Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.vr.sdk.widgets.pano.VrPanoramaView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/App7.App7-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/App7.App7-1/lib/arm64, /data/app/App7.App7-1/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
```

Comment: Can you upload a sample project that has the binding and a sample project to dig into further?

Comment: Here's a [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1y7arq2lo7gvlsw/AndroidVRtest.zip?dl=0) to a sample project. The **VRWidgetTest** folder contains the main project. The **Android** folder contains the projects for binding the Java libraries for your convenience. The **externals** folder inside that **Android** folder contains the original Google SDK Java code.